# Can't understand why function doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm new to Python3 and coding. I'am get stuck with a simple function.

```
import datetime

date = str(datetime.date.today())
mail = ""

text = (f"""   
some text {mail} 
some text {date}
some text
 """)

print(text)
def get_deadline_date():
    mail = "a@a.com"
print(text)
```

And I have

```
some text  
some text 2019-03-21
some text


some text  
some text 2019-03-21
some text
```

I can't change the text variable. 
It should print:

```
    some text a@a.com 
    some text 2019-03-21
    some text
```

As I understand, I made a simple mistake, but I can't figure it out.
 I tried,

```
import datetime

date = str(datetime.date.today())
mail = ""

text = (f"""   
some text {mail} 
some text {date}
some text
 """)

print(text)
def get_deadline_date():
    global mail
    mail = "a@a.com"
get_deadlin
```

It gave the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is defined but not executed. And, if it was executed, it would not change the value of `mail` because it has it's own namespace of variables, so it could access `mail` but not set it. What you are doing there is declaring a new variable, also called `mail` in that function. On top of that, your text is already set and will not update when you chnge the value of `mail`. I suggest this solution:

```
text = "some text {mail}\n" \
       "some text {date}\n" \
       "some text"


def make_text(text, date):
    mail = "a@a.com"
    return text.format(mail=mail, date=date)


text = make_text(text=text, date=date.today())
```

You may also want to make separate functions for setting `mail` and making the text, but remember to return the new `mail` you make to the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

- Mistake 1: You are not calling the function
- Mistake 2: `mail` is local variable (to function)
- Mistake 3: String is already evaluated/initialised

Bad, but your solution should  be

```
import datetime

date = str(datetime.date.today())
mail = ""

text = """   
some text {0} 
some text {1}
some text
 """.format


print(text(mail, date))
def get_deadline_date():
    global mail
    mail = "a@a.com"
get_deadline_date()
print(text(mail, date))
```

> Avoid global variable

Dedesign your code to avoid global variable, use function parameters and return values instead.

Comment: Just because the value of the `mail` variable changes doesn't mean the string in `text` will be updated as well...

Comment: The output is the same: some text  
some text 2019-03-21
some text
 
   
some text  
some text 2019-03-21
some text

Comment: Yes as @Aran-Fey mentioned the string is already initialized and changing mail does not change the text.

Comment: @LearntoFly Have updated the solution (still using global variable).